# Getting, "ValueError at /login/ The view account.views.login didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead." error

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

**I created a custom user model by extending AbstractBaseUser:**

```
class MyRegistration(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    location_list=[
        ('Solapur', 'Solapur'),
        ('Latur', 'Latur'),
        ('Dhule', 'Dhule'),
        ('Akola', 'Akola'),
        ('Nashik', 'Nashik')
        ]
    username=models.CharField(max_length=10, unique=True)
    email=models.EmailField(unique=True)
    first_name=models.CharField(max_length=150)
    last_name=models.CharField(max_length=150)
    location=models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=location_list, default='Latur')
    designation=models.CharField(max_length=70)
    is_active=models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_staff=models.BooleanField(default=False)
    start_date=models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    last_login=models.DateTimeField(null=True)


    USERNAME_FIELD='username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS=['email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'location', 'designation']
    objects=FirstManager()
    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

**And my manager loos something like this:**

```
class FirstManager(BaseUserManager):
    use_in_migrations=True
    def create_user(self, username, email, first_name, last_name, location, designation, password, **extra_fields):
        if not username:
            raise ValueError('Username is required!')
        email=self.normalize_email(email)
        user=self.model(username=username, email=email, first_name=first_name, last_name=last_name, location=location, designation=designation, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, username, email, first_name, last_name, location, designation, password, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_active', True)

        if extra_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must be assigned to is_staff=True.')
        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must be assigned to is_superuser=True.')
        return self.create_user(username, email, first_name, last_name, location, designation, password, **extra_fields)
```

**The registration form in forms.py:**

```
class MyRegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    password2=forms.CharField(label='Confirm', widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    class Meta:
        model=MyRegistration
        fields=['username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'location', 'designation']
```

**The Signup view:**

```
def signup(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        if request.POST.get('password1')==request.POST.get('password2'):
            try:
                user=MyRegistration.objects.get(username=request.POST.get('username'))
                return render (request, 'account/signup.html', {'error':'This username already exists!'})
            except MyRegistration.DoesNotExist:
                user=MyRegistration.objects.create_user(first_name=request.POST.get('first_name'),
                last_name=request.POST.get('last_name'),
                username=request.POST.get('username'),
                email=request.POST.get('email'),
                location=request.POST.get('location'),
                designation=request.POST.get('designation'),
                password=request.POST.get('password1'))
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/success/')
    else:
        fm=MyRegistrationForm()
        return render(request, 'account/signup.html', {'form':fm})

def success(request):
    return render(request, 'account/success.html')
```

**The login view:**

```
def login(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        if request.method == "POST":
            print(request.POST)
            fm = AuthenticationForm(request=request, data=request.POST)
            print(fm)
            if fm.is_valid():
                uname = fm.cleaned_data['username']
                upass = fm.cleaned_data['password']
                print(uname, upass)
                user = authenticate(username=uname, password=upass)
                if user is None:
                    print('Error')
                if user is not None:
                    print(user)
                    logs(request, user)
                    messages.success(request, 'Logged in successfully !!')
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/home/')
        else: 
            fm = AuthenticationForm()
            return render(request, 'account/login.html', {'form':fm})
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/home/')


def home(request):
    # print(request.user)
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return render(request, 'account/home.html', {'Name': request.user})
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/login/')
```

**The urls.py:**

```
from account import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('login/', views.login, name='login'),
    path('signup/', views.signup, name='signup'),
    path('home/', views.home, name='home'),
    path('success/', views.success, name='success'),
    path('logout/', views.user_logout, name='logout'),
    # path('laturhome/', vw.latur, name='laturhome'),
]
```

The signup works smoothly, but every time I try to log the user in it throws me this ValueError. What could possibly be the reason for this? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

#please update your view because your if fm.is_valid(): not handled via else

```
 def login(request):
        if not request.user.is_authenticated:
            if request.method == "POST":
                print(request.POST)
                fm = AuthenticationForm(request=request, data=request.POST)
                print(fm.errors)
                if fm.is_valid():
                    uname = fm.cleaned_data['username']
                    upass = fm.cleaned_data['password']
                    print(uname, upass)
                    user = authenticate(username=uname, password=upass)
                    if user is None:
                        print('Error')
                    if user is not None:
                        print(user)
                        logs(request, user)
                        messages.success(request, 'Logged in successfully !!')
                    return HttpResponseRedirect('/home/')
                else: 
                   return render(request, 'account/login.html', {'form':fm})
            else: 
                fm = AuthenticationForm()
                return render(request, 'account/login.html', {'form':fm})
        else:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/home/')
```

Comment: Thank you. But why is it not validating, any clue?

Comment: write below befor is_valid: you get error in terminal 
 
print(fm.errors)

Comment: Okay I tried that and it asks me to enter the correct username and password and that they might be case sensitive. But I have been entering the correct username and password all along and it's not even tricky that I would mess up their cases. Who knows where it all has gone wrong!

Comment: I'm sorry, which one is auth form? The one that I created, i.e forms.py, or the one in the Django's contrib folder? Pardon my lack of knowledge, I am a beginner. Please clear my confusion and I will provide you the detail.

Comment: If you are asking about the login form then there is none that I created. I have used AuthenticationForm from django. Though I think the problem lies there itself as the AuthenticationForm serves the Django's User model and I have created my own model using AbstractBaseUser. Do you also think that is the problem?

Comment: I just figured out that the authenticate method in the login view is not functioning properly even though the user exists in the database. I'm entering the username and password correctly too.